# Compiling C# GUI for win XP from a Windows 7 / VS2010 Dev Platform

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, c#-4.0

I'm currently developing a simple C# GUI in Visual studio 2010 Pro on a Win 7 X64 pc.  My problem arises when I try to run the application on different PC's.  The builds seem to work fine on all Win 7 machines however my release builds for x86 instantly fail when trying to execute the .exe on Win XP 32bit machines.

I thought C# was an interpreted language that would run on any machine running the current version of .net.  My source code is utilizing some of the .net libraries such as "System.IO.Ports" (SerialPort mainly) some functions from the "System.Linq" library as well as a "BackgroundWorker"

Are there any known issues for compiling for different platforms or some settings I have to have correct in the project properties page to have a runnable application on Win XP 32bit?

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: "instantly fail" is all you've told us about the failure mode. What's the full error message?

Comment: C# is not an interpreted language. It runs inside the .NET Framework. When you compile your application in Visual Studio you get build output in MSIL. The MSIL is then compiled down to native code just before your application runs. See this article for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6.aspx

Comment: 1. I believe I am using only the basic functionality of windows forms.

2. when trying to run the first thing that happens is I get the win XP error screen that says that the program has crashed, would you like to send the error data to Microsoft

3. Yes I understand the concepts of just in time compiling and I'm sorry I miss spoke and used interpretive so loosely...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed the .NET Framework 4.0 on the Windows XP PC?

Also, you can target earlier versions of .NET with Visual Studio 2010 if deploying .NET 4.0 is undesirable for whatever reason, and assuming your application doesn't use any .NET 4.0 features.

[See this MSDN article for more information.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx)

Have you changed your build target from Any to x86 (32 bit) only?

What is the full error message you are seeing?

Comment: I made sure to install .net 4.0 on all the xp machines before testing. I know you can add .net 4.0 as adjacent forced/suggested install with your application however this shouldn't necessary for my application as there will only be 4-5 users. But with .net 4.0 installed the application still failed to start.

Comment: Have you changed your build target from Any to x86 (32 bit) only?

Comment: Yes I went through all the build settings and set what I thought would be correct for an x86 build. I set it to do an x86 release build.

Comment: When your program crashes, does it offer you the ability to hook it up to the debugger? If so, have you tried that to see if an exception is visible in Visual Studio? Also, have you tried running Debug mode code to diagnose the issue rather than Release mode code?

Comment: Also in your Main method, you could wrap everything with a try {} catch (Exception ex){MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());} temporarily, that would catch any exception in your application.

Comment: When trying to run the debugger at crash time it opens up the assembly code.  This obviously inst of much use to me as interpreting assembly for C# would be quite challenging if not impossible.  I will try to catch the exception at run time with a "try catch" and a message box, this might shed some light on whats actually failing.

Comment: Ah, deploy debug mode code, run that, and attach the debugger to it when prompted. Also (in this situation only) make sure you deploy any PDB files from your build output directory. This will give you more information.

Comment: Will do, I'll let you know what the results are.

Comment: @tomfanning after sifting through the printed stack trace, it appears to be a problem with invoking the custom icon.ico.  For some reason Win7 seems to take what I give it and winXP crashes.  The error shown is: 

'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationExceptio:Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: the parameter is incorrect at System.Drawing.Icon.Initialize(Int32 width, Int32 height) ...' Leaving the icon as the default .net icon does not crash the program however my custom .icon does.  Any Ideas?

Comment: Not off the top. Glad to hear we found the problem though. Can I suggest you mark this question as answered and ask a fresh question? Tom

Answer (score 1):

My guess: you need to install .net 4.0 on those XP machines to get that executable to work.

C# executables run inside a virtual machine, but that virtual machine is not necessarily installed on all target machines. In the case of VS2010, it targets the latest version of .net, 4.0, which will often not be present on older XP machines.

Your VS2010 will have come with re-distributable packages for .net 4.0 so it should be easy enough to push them out to wherever's needed. However, exactly how you do that all depends on your local arrangements.